# Why does user.id is 'string' in default

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma, next-auth

I'm making a Next Auth system with typescript and I'm getting a type problem with the 'user.id' data. Error occurs on the callbacks section.

`The types of 'user.id' are incompatible between these types. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

this is the nextauth file:

```
interface CustomUser extends Omit<DefaultUser, 'id'> {
   id: number;
}

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
   providers: [
      CredentialsProvider({
         name: 'credentials',
         credentials: {
            badgeNumber: {
               label: 'badgenumber',
               type: 'text',
               placeholder: 'yourbadgenumber'
            },
            password: {
               label: 'Password',
               type: 'password'
            },
         },
         authorize: async (credentials) => {
            if (!credentials) {
               return null;
            }
            const { badgeNumber, password } = credentials;
            const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
               where: {
                  badgeNumber
               }
            });

            if (!user) return null;

            const userPassword = user.passwordHash;

            const isValidPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(password, userPassword)
            if (!isValidPassword) return null;
            return user;
         }
      })
   ],
   pages: {
      signIn: '/auth/signin',
      signOut: '/auth/signout',
   },
   secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
   jwt: {
      async encode({ secret, token }) {
         if (!token) {
            throw new Error('No token to encode');
         }
         return jwt.sign(token, secret);
      },
      async decode({ secret, token }) {
         if (!token) {
            throw new Error('No token to decode');
         }
         const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, secret);
         if (typeof decodedToken === 'string') {
            return JSON.parse(decodedToken);
         } else {
            return decodedToken;
         }
      }
   },
   session: {
      strategy: 'jwt',
      maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
      updateAge: 24 * 60 * 60,
   },
   callbacks: {
      async session(params: { session: Session; token: JWT; user: CustomUser }) {
         if (params.session.user) {
            params.session.user.id = typeof params.token.id === 'string' ? parseInt(params.token.id, 10) : params.token.id;
            params.session.user.badgeNumber = params.token.badgeNumber;
            params.session.user.department = params.token.department;
            params.session.user.rank = params.token.rank;
            params.session.user.admin = params.token.admin;
            params.session.user.superadmin = params.token.superadmin;
            params.session.user.name = params.token.name;
            params.session.user.createdPassword = params.token.createdPassword
         }
         return params.session;
      },
      async jwt(params: {
         token: JWT;
         user?: User | undefined;
      }) {
         if (params.user) {
            params.token.id = params.user.id;
            params.token.badgeNumber = params.user.badgeNumber;
            params.token.department = params.user.department;
            params.token.rank = params.user.rank;
            params.token.admin = params.user.admin;
            params.token.superadmin = params.user.superadmin;
            params.token.name = params.user.name;
            params.token.createdPassword = params.user.createdPassword;
         }
         console.log(params.token)
         return params.token;
      }
   }
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

this is the next-auth-extensions i made

```
interface CustomUser extends Omit<DefaultUser, 'id'> {
    user: {
        id: number;
    }
}
declare module "next-auth" {
    interface Session extends CustomUser {
        user: {
            /** The user's id */
            badgeNumber: string,
            passwordHash: string,
            department: number,
            rank: number,
            admin?: boolean,
            superadmin?: boolean,
            name: string,
            createdPassword: boolean,
            id: number,
        };
    }

    interface User extends DefaultUser {
        badgeNumber: string,
        passwordHash: string,
        department: number,
        rank: number,
        admin?: boolean,
        superadmin?: boolean,
        name: string,
        createdPassword: boolean,
        id: number
    }
}


declare module 'next-auth/jwt' {
    interface JWT extends Omit<DefaultJWT, 'id'> {
        badgeNumber: string,
        passwordHash: string,
        department: number,
        rank: number,
        admin?: boolean,
        superadmin?: boolean,
        name: string,
        createdPassword: boolean,
        id: number
    }
}
```

parsing int, number and many more things but it keeps coming. There is no string id in any line of this app but it still occurs.

Comment: Probably, because typically the claims of a JWT are of type `string`. I don't know which library you are using, but have a look at its JWT interface. So `params.token.id` will always be `string` and you cannot assign a `string` to a `number` ...

Comment: I extended the next-auth's JWT interface and added my id as a number, it works fine but this error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Because `next-auth` under the hood fallbacks the id to `crypto.randomUUID()` when the provider does not provide an `id`.

[From the next-auth implementation](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/d7a116558700785880ecb03658b7de7c98bcf4bf/packages/core/src/lib/actions/callback/index.ts#L311):

```
id: userFromAuthorize?.id?.toString() ?? crypto.randomUUID(),
```

If your provider provides an id, it'll be converted to string. If not it will use `randomUUID()`

To ship your custom id as a number to the session object you can add another field such as `userId: number`.